# How can I use fonts for a special word in latex?

Tags: fonts

How can i use special font for a word, like Verdana, Times New Roman, Tahoma, ... in Latex?

How can define command for any above font and use that in text?

Comment: use lualaex (or xelatex) not pdflatex then the fontspec package lets you use any font that you can use in Word

Comment: @DavidCarlisle,could you write command for example for Verdana?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XeLaTeX for easily switching fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}

\newfontfamily\asana{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
    {\asana Asana math font}.\\
    
    Normal font uses old standard.
\end{document}
```

This is the output
[image]

Answer (score 4):

An example with **Verdana** using the engine `LuaLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Verdana}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 'microsoft sans serif' is my favorite font in MS Word - Can you tell me how to replace 'Verdana' font with 'microsoft sans serif' in the above LaTeX code if it is possible? Thanks!!

Comment: @Dr.Sundar Very kind sorry but I have not the fonts of microsoft sans serif for LaTeX. :-((( sorry again